# PnP JS Core : Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: pnp, typescript, pnp-js-core, pnpjs, angular2

I am using PnP js in one of my angular 6 project.

I have a function which is defined in the Component, but I am getting this error at run-time when calling from inside the `success` of PnP SP js:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

I guess, within PnP block, `this` keyword is not working.

Any suggestion/solution?

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: RESOLVED : It was my mistake, which I have fixed. No issue with PnP core